# How to use Angular CurrencyPipe to display money in thousands

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have some salary information that I want to display in the format: $55k

Using the CurrencyPipe I display:

```
{{salary | currency:'USD'}}
```

This will show as

```
$55,000.00
```

Can you use the CurrencyPipe to display in 'k', with 1 decimal point if necessary.

Eg. $55340 will display as $55.3k

Comment: You need to write a custom pipe to replace thousands with K

Comment: Here's a similar pipe for displaying file sizes in MB you could copy to write your own. https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-pipes-custom-pipes

Comment: You can see what's supported functionality [in the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe); for anything else, you'll have to extend it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across how to do this. You use digitInfo like so:

{{(salary/1000) | currency:'USD': 'symbol':'1.0-1'}}k